# Unable to testcustom policy in AD B2C, No applications listed to run

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have done all the configurations and registered required the web applications to create user flows and custom policies in Azure Active Directory B2C by following this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#test-the-custom-policy.

But after uploading my custom policies I'm not able to run them , in the run screen I can't see any application listed. I'm attaching the screenshot here.
This is what I can see when I try to run any of my custom policies like SignupSignIn, ForgotPassword etc.

Please help me on this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Gf8M.png)

Answer (score 0):

What does the "App Registrations" tab show?

Did you [create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-applications?tabs=app-reg-ga) an app. registration?